# Tikz/Pgf - Surf plot with smooth color transition

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, gnuplot, smooth

I am drawing a `surf` 3d plot in `Tikz/Pgf` using `gnuplot`. This surface need to be projected on a plane, which can be achieved by adding another `surf` plot.

The thing is that the transition between colors, in both `surf` plots actually is not very smooth, despite using

```
shader=interp
```

One possibility is to increase the number of `samples` however building becomes slow and I cannot exceed 75 samples.

An example code can be found right next

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}    [width=\textwidth,
                     height=\textwidth,
                     ultra thick,
                     colorbar,
                     colorbar style={yticklabel style={text width=2.5em,
                                                      align=right,
                                                  /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                                   fixed,
                                                   fixed zerofill,
                                                   precision=1,
                                                   },
                                    },
                     xlabel={$\rho_x=k_xr_x$},
                     ylabel={$\rho_y=k_yr_y$},
                     zlabel={$j_l(\rho)$},
                     3d box,
                     zmax=2.5,
                     xmin=-3, xmax=3,
                 ymin=-3.1, ymax=3.1,
                 ytick={-3, -2, ..., 3},
                 grid=major,
                     grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!30, dashed},
                     x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=1
                                    },
                y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=1
                                    },
                z tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=1
                                    },
                    ]
        \addplot3[surf, 
                      shader=interp,
                      mesh/ordering=y varies,
                      domain=-3:3,
                      y domain=-3.1:3.1,
                      ]
             gnuplot {besj0(x**2+y**2)};

         \addplot3[surf,
                  samples=51,
                  shader=interp,
                  mesh/ordering=y varies,
                  domain=-3:3,
                  y domain=-3.1:3.1,
                  point meta=rawz,
                  z filter/.code={\def\pgfmathresult{2.5}},
                  ]
             gnuplot {besj0(x**2+y**2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and the result of this code is the following image

[image]

Any idea on how to make a smoother transition from color to color?

Comment: With pleasure! No problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your main concern is the color transitions, then you may want to use a polar plot because the function only depends on the radius and not on the angle. Then you could increase the samples in radial direction while leaving the samples in angular direction comparatively small.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}    [width=\textwidth,
                     height=\textwidth,
                     ultra thick,
                     colorbar,
                     colorbar style={yticklabel style={text width=2.5em,
                                                      align=right,
                                                  /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                                   fixed,
                                                   fixed zerofill,
                                                   precision=1,
                                                   },
                                    },
                     xlabel={$\rho_x=k_xr_x$},
                     ylabel={$\rho_y=k_yr_y$},
                     zlabel={$j_l(\rho)$},
                     3d box,
                     zmax=2.5,
                     xmin=-3, xmax=3,
                     ymin=-3.1, ymax=3.1,
                     ytick={-3, -2, ..., 3},
                     grid=major,
                     grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!30, dashed},
                     x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=1
                                    },
                     y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=1
                                    },
                     z tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=1
                                    }, 
                    data cs=polar,
                    ]
        \addplot3[surf, samples=37,samples y=101,
                      shader=interp,
                      z buffer=sort,
                      %mesh/ordering=y varies,
                      domain=0:360,
                      y domain=3.1:0,
                      ]
             gnuplot {besj0(y**2)};

        \addplot3[surf, samples=36, samples y=101,
                      shader=interp,
                      %mesh/ordering=y varies,
                      domain=0:360,
                      y domain=0:3.1,
                      point meta=rawz,
                      z filter/.code={\def\pgfmathresult{2.5}},
                      ]
             gnuplot {besj0(y**2)};


    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a "side-effect" the wiggles will also disappear as they result from plotting a rotationally symmetric function in cartesian coordinates.

And here is a combination of a cartesian and a polar plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}    [width=\textwidth,
                     height=\textwidth,
                     ultra thick,
                     colorbar,
                     colorbar style={yticklabel style={text width=2.5em,
                                                      align=right,
                                                  /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                                   fixed,
                                                   fixed zerofill,
                                                   precision=1,
                                                   },
                                    },
                     xlabel={$\rho_x=k_xr_x$},
                     ylabel={$\rho_y=k_yr_y$},
                     zlabel={$j_l(\rho)$},
                     3d box,
                     zmax=2.5,
                     xmin=-3, xmax=3,
                     ymin=-3.1, ymax=3.1,
                     ytick={-3, -2, ..., 3},
                     grid=major,
                     grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!30, dashed},
                     x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=1
                                    },
                     y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=1
                                    },
                     z tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=1
                                    }, 
                    ]
        \addplot3[surf, samples=75,
                      shader=interp,
                      mesh/ordering=y varies,
                      domain=-3:3,
                      y domain=-3.1:3.1,
                      ]
             gnuplot {besj0(x**2+y**2)};
        \addplot3[surf, samples=36, samples y=101,
                      shader=interp,
                      %mesh/ordering=y varies,
                      domain=0:360,
                      y domain=0:3.1,
                      point meta=rawz,
                      data cs=polar,
                      z filter/.code={\def\pgfmathresult{2.5}},
                      ]
             gnuplot {besj0(y**2)};


    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The point is that in the 3d surface the folding of the function is more prominent, therefore the wiggles are indeed needed! I could however use a polar plot on the projection. Is this possible?

Comment: @Thanos Yes, but I do not understand what you mean by "folding".

Comment: I mean the wiggles you mentioned in the side-effect.

Comment: @Thanos But aren't the wiggles "unphysical", meaning that the true Bessel function doesn't have them (since they imply an angular dependence, which J0 does not have)?

Comment: @ marmot You are perfectly right. However, I believe that for illustration reasons, someone can better observe the oscillating behaviour.

Comment: @Thanos If you really want the wiggles, you could add them. (You could, for instance, add a Jn with some nontrivial n multiplied by a small coefficient.) Otherwise you will never be really able to control their size, and, what is more, nor their location. As you see, they mainly occur in your figure at x ~ y, but not x ~ - y, which appears odd to me given that the function has a rotational symmetry.

Comment: It also appeared strange to me, but I thought it had to do with how the cross-section of the surface plot in each plane.

Comment: @Thanos Yes, something like this might be the reason. But if you want to depict J0, I think the wiggles should not be there, simply since J0 has a rotational symmetry.